# How to migrate my users table in Laravel after I made a change?

Tags: php, laravel

I am building an eCommerce site and I am running into an issue when migrating my orders table. I am getting the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'orders_user_id_foreign' are incompatible. (SQL: alter table `orders` add constraint `orders_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete set null on update cascade)
```

The schema that sets up the foreign key for this migration looks like:

```php
// set up foreign key on users
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable(); // will be null if guest
$table->foreign('user_id')
    ->references('id')->on('users')
    ->onUpdate('cascade')
    ->onDelete('set null');
```

I figured out that the `users` table schema sets up the id like so:

```
$table->id();
```

And the `orders` table schema sets up the id like this:

```
$table->increments('id');
```

So I changed the `users` migration so that it is the same as the `orders` migration i.e both are like:

```
$table->increments('id');
```

But when I run `php artisan migrate`, I get this back:

```
➜  MobileMastery_V2 git:(master) ✗ php artisan migrate  --path=/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php
Nothing to migrate.
```

As you can see above I tried declaring the path to the migration I wanted to see if that would work but it didn't. How can I get this single file to migrate? Thanks

Comment: The two columns must match **exactly**, which means that the user_id on the orders table cannot be null. It might be better to set a default guest user ID.

Comment: for the order table ``user_id`` should be also the same as the ``id`` from the user table but you have changed the order id column instead of user_id from the order table.

Comment: `$table->id();` create **unsigned big integer** so change integer to bigInteger `$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel migrations are intended to keep track of the changes you make on your database over time. Laravel creates a table called `migrations` that keeps track of the migrations if it already ran or not. So in this case you can create a new migration that only makes that change, or if your database has no data on it yet you can drop the database schema, make your modifications on the migrations and run it again.

And about the primary key and foreign keys, I recommend you to read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) part of Laravel documentation.

You should create migration for this change and run `php artisan migrate`.

Comment: Thank you for this